# intel C++ compiler for Windows turn-off vectorization

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, intel, vectorization

I use Intel C++ Compiler v. 13 for OS Windows in MS Visual Studio 2010. This compiler support vectorize a code. I want to disable this option, but save enabled -O2 optimization. I set for this goal `/Qvec-` flag in `Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line -> Additional Options` window (label "Inherit from parent or project defaults" is enabled). In All options section shown these keys:

> /Zi /nologo /W3 /Od /Ot /Qipo /Qopt-matmul /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D
>   "_CONSOLE" /D "NOALIAS" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /EHsc /MT /GS /Gy
>   /fp:fast /QaxAVX /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Qopenmp /Qstd=c99
>   /Qstd=c++11 /Fp"Release\mformat.pch" /Fa"Release\" /Fo"Release\"
>   /Fd"Release\vc100.pdb" /Qvec-report2 /Gd

But in compilation report output this messages:

> service.cpp(164): warning : SIMD LOOP WAS VECTORIZED.
>
> service.cpp(535): warning : SIMD LOOP WAS VECTORIZED.
>
> service.cpp(543): warning : loop was not vectorized: nonstandard loop
>   is not a vectorization candidate.
>
> etc...

And program time is not change. How i can disable vectorization and no set `\Od` key?

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the document ["A Guide to Vectorization with Intel® C++ Compilers"](http://download-software.intel.com/sites/default/files/8c/a9/CompilerAutovectorizationGuide.pdf)

> To allow comparisons of vectorized with unvectorized code,
>   vectorization may be disabled with the switch /Qvec- (Windows*) or
>   -no-vec (Linux* or Mac OS* X).

Lots of additional good information on the [Intel® Composer XE Suite](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-composer-xe) page.